# Evaluate a complex integral.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I looked around but I couldn't find if this question has been asked before.

Given two polynomials $P(z) = a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$ and $Q(z)=z^n+b_{n-1}z^{n-1}_ + \cdots + b_0,$ prove for sufficently large $r>0$
$$ \int_{|z|=r} \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)} dz =  2 \pi a_{n-1} i$$

My attempt: I tried to do this integral directly by computing the residues directly depending on if the root occurs multiple or times or not. But I failed. Should I try this method again, or a hint for another direction would be appreciated.

EDIT: By fail, I mean there was no reason that they should sum to the desired result.

Comment: Computing the residues directly would be much harder than using Rouche's theorem.

Comment: Note that $\frac {P(z)dz}{Q(z)}=(ia_{n-1}+O(1/r))d\theta$ so letting $r \to \infty$ gives you the result noting that for $r$ higher than the poles the integral doesn't depend on $r$

Comment: @NinadMunshi I have a solution now. But I am curious what did you have in my in regarding Rouche's Theorem.

Comment: Also, @Conrad thanks again.

Comment: Happy to be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $  \dfrac{z^j}{Q(z)} = O(|z|^{j-n})$ as $|z| \to \infty$ for $0 \le j < n-1$,
while $ \dfrac{z^{n-1}}{Q(z)} = \dfrac{1}{z} + O(|z|^{-2})$

Comment: Thanks Robert. The hint helped a lot and I have a nice solution to add to my binder now.